# Origen de la expresión "acción de gracias"

Tags: traducción, etimología, expresiones

Ahora que se acerca el *Thanksgiving Day* o "día de acción de gracias" como le decimos por aquí, me surgió ayer en una conversación el tema de que "acción de gracias" es una expresión extraña en español, dado que para eso tenemos el verbo *agradecer*, y por tanto podríamos llamarlo el "día del agradecimiento" o algo así.

La verdad es que la pregunta me intrigó, así que la comparto con vosotros. ¿Por qué se dice "acción de gracias" y no "agradecimiento" o algún otro término o expresión que suene menos extraño? ¿Cuál es el origen de esta expresión?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando me surgen estas preguntas muchas veces me pregunto si no será al revés, si no será la expresión inglesa una adaptación de una expresión que existía en lenguas romances desde mucho antes. Y por lo que vamos a ver en esta respuesta, posiblemente sea así, aunque del origen de la expresión inglesa no nos vamos a ocupar ya que no pertenece al ámbito de este sitio. De momento, vamos a dar un paseo por el tiempo que nos va a llevar bastante lejos.

Lo primero es aclarar por qué actualmente decimos "acción de gracias" y no "agradecimiento" o algo parecido. La respuesta está en el diccionario. Un [agradecimiento](https://dle.rae.es/agradecimiento) es la acción de mostrar gratitud o dar las gracias, definición que, si nos fijamos, ya incluye las palabras "acción de gracias". Sin embargo, la expresión *[acción de gracias](https://dle.rae.es/acci%C3%B3n#6b0ZM4L)* significa:

> Expresión o manifestación pública de agradecimiento normalmente dirigida a la divinidad.

Es decir, incluye los conceptos de "agradecimiento público" y "agradecimiento dirigido a lo divino". Lo cual cuadra con la definición de *[thanksgiving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/thanksgiving)* en inglés:

> the act of saying or showing that you are grateful, especially to God

Bien, las definiciones cuadran, pero ¿de dónde viene esta expresión? Pues vamos allá.

La primera parada en nuestro viaje es el *Diccionario de Autoridades*. Allá por 1726 la RAE escribía en su primer diccionario lo siguiente:

> ACCION DE GRACIAS. Es el acto devoto, rendido, y humilde, con que se reconoce y dá gracias à la Magestád Divina por los beneficios recibidos. Dicese tambien hacimiento de gracias.

Por tanto, en el siglo XVIII ya se usaba la expresión con el mismo significado que hoy. Si buscamos estas expresiones en el CORDE, encontramos textos mucho más antiguos que el *Autoridades* que usan la expresión. La siguiente parada es en el siglo XIV para leer el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Et nos, los sobredichos abbat et conuiento, la sobredicha donacion, en la forma et manera que sobre escripta es, con acciones de gracias la rescebimos et acceptamos, et prometemos por nos et por uuestros successores en perpetuo de fazer tener, obseruar et complescer todas et cada unas cosas sobre escriptas, et a esto fazer et complescer obligamos todos et cada unos bienes del dicho monesterio, conjuntament et diuisament.*
>
> Anónimo, "Donación de unas casas", 1385 (España).

Se podría entender que aquí la expresión se usa de forma más genérica, pero dado que el contexto incluye un convento y un monasterio, posiblemente la acción de gracias se refiera a agradecer a Dios el recibir la donación. A fin de cuentas, en esa misma época ya se usaba el verbo *agradecer*:

> *Desi que se ofrecia a servicio del Rey en esta guerra de los moros cada que el Rey quisiese por su cuerpo entrar a tierra de moros entendiendo servir a Dios e a su senyor el Rey de Castiella e a ell. Et esto le agradecio mucho el Rey darago e dixo quel placia mucho con su venida.*
>
> Anónimo, "Embajada de los Reyes de Aragón al de Castilla", 1334 (España).

Nótese que aquí el agradecimiento sí se dirige a una persona, y no a una divinidad. Con todo, aún no hemos llegado al origen de la expresión. Ya hemos visto por qué en determinados contextos se prefería *acción de gracias* sobre *agradecimiento*. Incluso la versión *hacimiento de gracias* se encuentra en el siglo XIII en textos similares de agradecimiento a Dios:

> *Loaré el Tu Nombre con cántigo
>
> & enalçarl'e con fazimiento de gracias,
>
> et plazrá a Dios más que buey & vezerro,
>
> que crescen cuernos & vnnas; [...]*
>
> Herman el Alemán, "Traslación del Psalterio", c 1240 - 1272 (España).

Para ver el origen podemos dar otro salto e irnos a finales del siglo XV a leer el diccionario español-latino de Nebrija, escrito en 1495:

> Agradecer por palabra. ago gratias
> Agradecimiento assi. actio gratiarum

Y aquí está el quid de la cuestión. Resulta que "acción de gracias" no es más que la traducción literal de la expresión latina que significaba "agradecimiento". Aunque en realidad esta traducción podría hacer uso del latín medieval. En latín clásico la expresión era *gratiarum actionem*. Esta expresión se puede encontrar en textos de España escritos en latín en el siglo X:

> *Ideoque ob honorem et gratiarum actionem Creatoris nostri Ihesu Christi et ad laudem nominis eius [...]*
>
> Anónimo, "Sancho Garcés I y la reina Toda fundan el monasterio de San Martin de Albelda", 924 (España).

Nuevamente la expresión usada para dar gracias a Dios. De hecho el origen último lo podemos encontrar en el latín clásico. El último salto temporal que daremos nos lleva a leer *[De Legibus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_legibus)*, escrito por Marco Tulio Cicerón alrededor del año 52 a.C., donde encontramos lo siguiente:

> *[...] quamquam gratiarum actionem a te non desiderabam [...].*

Literalmente: "aunque no quería darte las gracias".

La composición de la expresión viene de *actio*, literalmente "la puesta en marcha de algo", y *[gratia](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DG%3Aentry%20group%3D15%3Aentry%3Dgratia)*, en este contexto "señal de agradecimiento por un servicio prestado, gracias, agradecimiento, gratitud". Todo junto vendría a ser algo así como "la puesta en marcha de un agradecimiento". Usábase esta expresión en cualquier contexto.

Conforme el español fue evolucionando, el verbo *agradecer* fue desbancando a *acción de gracias*, salvo en contextos eclesiásticos, donde el idioma latín se mantuvo durante mucho más tiempo que en el habla común de la calle. Fue por tanto en el ámbito de la iglesia donde se pudo mantener la expresión *acción de gracias*, reflejo español del latín *gratiarum actionem* o *actio grationem* según Nebrija. De hecho, la parte de la misa llamada *[eucaristía](https://dle.rae.es/eucarist%C3%ADa)* significa literalmente "acción de gracias" en latín tardío, y antes en griego clásico. Esto hizo que la expresión acabara siendo usada solamente en el sentido de "dar las gracias a Dios".

Comment: Sería un anglicismo si fuera algo como "dación/dádiva de gracias" ;) Interesante contribución, como siempre.